# what is right jQuery event for a input field with timepicker

Tags: ajax, jquery, events

I have a input field that is  formatted with the data-format `HH:mm:ss PP`. When the timepicker is clicked the `focus` on the input field don't appear that's why I couldn't use `onblur` event. What i want is like `keydown` or `keyup` event but it seems doesn't work in my case because `focus` is out in the input field so what jQuery event should i used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`change` seems to work fine:

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PVb9x/1/)

```
  $("#datepicker").datepicker()
  .on("change", function () {
      console.log("Changed");
  });
```

Example is with `datepicker()`, I'm not sure what your `timepicker` implementation is as it's not in the jquery(ui) api. But it should work as well.

---

Edit: after looking at the datetimepicker you are using, based on the DOM I'm seeing as a result of `datetimepicker()` - I think this should work for you:

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PVb9x/2/)

```
$('#datetimepicker1').closest(".well").next(".bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget").on("click", "*", function () {
    console.log("Changed");
});
```

Just make sure this is after your `datetimepicker()` call. Note that this will be triggered on any click within your calendar/time picker even if it is a click on something that is already selected (no change).

If you want, you could store the last value of your input and then check that if it changed before continuing with this event callback function. If it did change, be sure to update the variable you are holding the "last value" in... something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/PVb9x/3/).

---

If possible, the best option would actually be to modify `datetimepicker()`'s js to call a function or trigger an event from the same place it updates the text input. Looking at the code:

```
    set: function () {
        var formatted = "";
        if (!this._unset) formatted = this.formatDate(this._date);
        if (!this.isInput) {
            if (this.component) {
                var input = this.$element.find("input");
                input.val(formatted);
                input.trigger("change"); // added this
                this._resetMaskPos(input)
            }
            this.$element.data("date", formatted)
        } else {
            this.$element.val(formatted);
            this.$element.trigger("change"); //added this
            this._resetMaskPos(this.$element)
        }
    },
```

With the two lines I added above, you should be able to rely on a `change` event bound to the `input` element.

Comment: I doesn't work either man. I use http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ for my ui.

Comment: @smemy it doesn't work for me man. if i put it the code the icon disappears and wont work

Comment: @LeonardDrapeza well you can't use `datepicker()` if you are using a timepicker. You have to select the element.

Comment: @smemy it's a datetimepicker actually but there is a configuration for timepicker, what particular element? I did use the id `$('#datetimepicker2')` and i tried to `alert()` something but it doesn't work. it only works for `$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker`

Comment: @LeonardDrapeza, i looked at some of the examples from datetimepicker, it seems they all wrap the content within `.well` and then when the `datetimepicker()` is applied, it appends the calendar picker to the dom after well. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @LeonardDrapeza, thanks for accepting this answer, but if you wouldn't mind sharing which solution you chose - I'd be interested in knowing.

Comment: Sorry I think my question is not well explained in here that's why I created another question. LOL :)) Here's the thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279115/cant-find-the-proper-event-for-input-field-with-timepicker