# cant find the proper event for input field with timepicker

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-selectors

I have an input field with timepicker I used [bootstrap calendar](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) for my `UI` and have this config for timepicker purpose:

```
   <div class='input-append' id='datetimepicker2' >
            <input data-format='HH:mm:ss PP' type='text' name="start_time" id="start_time" value="<?php echo set_value('start_time')?>"/>
            <span class='add-on'>
              <i data-date-icon='icon-calendar' data-time-icon='icon-time'>
              </i>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
          $(function() {
            $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
              language: 'en',
              pick12HourFormat: true,
              pickDate: false
            });

          });

        </script>
```

what im working is that if I'm done entering data using the timepicker from `start_time` to `end_time` I automatically calculate the `total_time` but I dont know where to fire the event. I could'nt use `onchange` ,`onblur` because the focus is **NOT** on the input field but on the timepicker icon. It's not working either when i use `$('#datetimepicker2').click` or any event in the timepicker, just the `$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker` itself works. So where do i put the `event` or what specific event do i needed to do that? any help? coz i'm really stuck in here for so long

Comment: does the answer below solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using changeDate event.

```
$('#datetimepicker2').datepicker()
  .on('changeDate', function(ev){

  });
```